# How to combine an animation_list with another background

Tags: android, android-xml

I have two backgrounds that I'm willing to apply to a single Button. The first background is about the shape and the second is an animation-list. 
The problem is if I want to enable animation I have to set animation-list as the Button background, in that case I'm not able to set Button shape since it requires to be set as Button background.

Here you have the xml:

Button

```
<Button
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:padding="@dimen/medium_padding"
                    android:text="Search here !"
                    android:textAllCaps="false"
                    android:background="@drawable/gradient_list" />
```

Curved shape xml

```
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:shape="rectangle">
<corners android:radius="30dp" />
<solid android:color="@color/colorWhite" />
<stroke
    android:width="1dp"
    android:color="@color/colorYellow" />
</shape>
```

Animation_list

```
<animation-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <item android:drawable="@drawable/gradient_1"
        android:duration="4000"/>

    <item android:drawable="@drawable/gradient_2"
        android:duration="2000"/>

    <item android:drawable="@drawable/gradient_3"
        android:duration="4000"/>

</animation-list>
```

Answer (score 0):

inside of the gradient_1/gradient_2/gradient_3 shapes, you should be able to add in all of the items you have in curved_shape.xml. for me, I had this and it worked:

loading_animation.xml

```
<animation-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

<item
    android:drawable="@drawable/loading_gradient_start"
    android:duration="300" />

<item
    android:drawable="@drawable/loading_gradient_center"
    android:duration="300" />

<item
    android:drawable="@drawable/loading_gradient_end"
    android:duration="300" />
```

loading_gradient_start.xml

```
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:shape="rectangle">
<corners android:radius="10dp"/>

<gradient
    android:angle="180"
    android:centerColor="@color/a"
    android:endColor="@color/b"
    android:startColor="@color/c"
    android:type="linear" />
```